# Creating a joined table with laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, database-migration

I am using Laravel 6. I want to create a joined table named `meeting_user` that should connect the tables `meetings` and `users`. That's considering that a user could participate to many meetings and a meeting could have many users.

**users:**

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('surname');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('username')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->enum('permission', array(0, 1, 2));
    $table->enum('is_active', array(0, 1))->default(1);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**meetings:**

```php
Schema::create('meetings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->string('id_room');
    $table->date('date');
    $table->time('start_hour');
    $table->time('end_hour');
    $table->enum('is_active', array(0, 1))->default(1);;
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('id_room')->references('id')->on('rooms');
});
```

I would like to create this table with a migration and furthermore I would like that when a user creates a meeting with many users and so inserts a new row to the "meetings" table, even the new "meeting_user" table be dynamically filled in adding new rows. Is there a way to do that with Laravel?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: "*I would like to create this table with a migration*" - Well that part's easy, `php artisan make:migration create_meeting_user_table` (or similar), with `user_id` and `meeting_id`, and any additional pivot data. The second part is not so simple. You need an interface for creating the meeting and assigning Users that will take part, and the Controller logic to handle `attach()`ing those users. This is a little too broad in its current state. You're expected to try to solve your issue before asking a question about it, as Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create a third table 
called for example "user_meetings"
and it's migration will be

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('meeting_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')- 
    >onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('meeting_id')->references('id')->on('meetings')- 
    >onDelete('cascade');
```

and then put the relation in "user" model

```
   public function meetings()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Meeting::class, 'user_meetings', 'user_id', 'meeting_id');
    }
```

and the relation in "meeting" model

```
 public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_meetings', 'meeting_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

and the code of "adding" meetings in the controller will be

```
 $user->meetings()->attach($request->meetings);
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'successfull');
```

and "edit"

```
   $checker->meetings()->sync($request->meetings);
                return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'successfull');
```

and "delete"

```
$checker->meetings()->detach();
```

i hope these steps will help you

Comment: you mean users() should just "belongsTo" ?